# Flutter IOS Distribution failed with errors

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, deployment

**Flutter build ios** runs successfully and i have all the icons in the Assets.xcassets folder yet I still keep getting this error:

[image]

[image]

Its saying CFBundleIcons yet my plist file doesn't have that key.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>$(DEVELOPMENT_LANGUAGE)</string>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>Sellet</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>Sellet</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>$(FLUTTER_BUILD_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>$(FLUTTER_BUILD_NUMBER)</string>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Post Photos</string>
    <key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Post Photos</string>
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>LaunchScreen</string>
    <key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>
    <string>Main</string>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
    <false/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I've tried adding the icon files one by one inside xcode itself but i got the same error. Does anyone know how to fix this? Please help. Thank you

Comment: Is the "App Icons Source" in your target set to the correct asset group? Another thing to check is whether your icon images are all EXACTLY the dimensions specified in those error messages, and in .png format.

Comment: I've been stuck on the same problem for a day now, have you found a solution? - I've looked at other solutions to similar problems and have tried readding all files, verifying that the target membership is to my project, ensuring the icon is linked under App icons in General tab and adding all of the files in build phases. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I used the flutter_launcher_icons package to generate the icons, then i edited the Contents.json to make sure all the paths and sizes were correct. I then opened XCode and there were some unused icon which i deleted and it worked.

Comment: Wow, finally got it to work! Thanks! I created a new project and instead of deleting the icon folder and replacing it with a generated one I got from an icon generator online I used the flutter_launcher_icons package, which only replaced the icons.